# R - Select IDs only if some conditions are met per group

Tags: r, select, group-by, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a recommender that will recommend the right people for a specific activity based on the skills people have.
To do so, I first built a recommendation engine that gives the skills recommendations per activity based on historical data (the skills owned by the people who worked on these activities).
Now, the trick is to associate these to some specific people.

I'm not quite sure about the smartest way to do it but the easiest way would be to look for the recommended skills of a specific activity, and match with the employees who have, for instance, at least 50% of these skills.

My dataset looks like this:

```
Region    ActivityID   Recommended_Skills     PersonID     Skills_Person
France    123          Python                 ABC          R
France    123          PowerPoint             ABC          Mikado
France    123          R                      ABC          Python
France    123          Word                   ABC          Photoshop    
France    123          Python                 XYZ          Finance
France    123          PowerPoint             XYZ          Powerpoint    
France    123          R                      XYZ          Law
France    123          Word                   XYZ          Analytics    
Spain     789          JavaScript             DEF          PowerPoint
Spain     789          PowerPoint             DEF          Word    
Spain     789          UI                     DEF          R
Spain     789          Office                 DEF          Finance    
Spain     789          Python                 CVB          JavaScript
Spain     789          PowerPoint             CVB          Office
```

Basically in this case, my expected dataframe should look like this:

```
Region    ActivityID     PersonID
France    123            ABC
Spain     789            CVB
```

In fact, DEF is not recommended for activity 123 in that case since there needs to be a group_by "Region". Also, in this case only one person is recommended per ActivityID but there should be more normally.

I hope this was clear enough; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Allan

Comment: Is the logic correct `df1 %>% group_by(Region, ActivityID, PersonID) %>% mutate(sn = sum(unique(Skills_Person) %in% Recommended_Skills)/n() >= 0.5 )`

Comment: My question is that whether the Recommended_Skills is for the entire column to compare or by group

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks for the answer. The recommended_Skills is per Activity. I've tried to run the code above but I have no match between the Skills_Person and the Recommend_Skills for a specific Activity.

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` way would be

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Region, ActivityID) %>%
  summarise(PersonID = names(which.max(map_dbl(split(Skills_Person, PersonID), 
                        ~sum(Recommended_Skills %in% .)))))


#  Region ActivityID PersonID
#  <chr>  <chr>      <chr>   
#1  France 123        ABC     
#2  Spain  789        CVB
```

We group for every `Region` and `Activity` and find a `PersonID` which has a maximum matching skill with the `Recommended_Skills` for that `ActivityID`.